# Compilation errors on stored procedure

Tags: oracle, syntax, procedure

I am typically a SQL Server developer however am now working with a system that uses Oracle. I have created a new procedure and am getting a runtime error. Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHK_LASTAPPTIME 
(
    LASTAPPTIME OUT VARCHAR2  
) 
IS
    v_appappid varchar2(20) null;
    v_lastapptime number null;
BEGIN
    select max(APPID) into v_appappid from applicationtable;

    select trunc(v_lastapptime = (((sysdate - capturedate) * 24)) * 60) from applicationtable where APPID = v_appappid;

    LASTAPPTIME := to_char(v_lastapptime);

END CHK_LASTAPPTIME;
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
SQL> var x varchar2;
SQL> exec CHK_LASTAPPTIME(:x);
BEGIN CHK_LASTAPPTIME(:x); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "CAPDEV.CHK_LASTAPPTIME", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your proecedure doesn't have 19 lines, so the message is odd, or you've shown different code to what you're actually running. Since what you've shown doesn't compile I'm assuming you've tried to cut it down for the question, and I'll also assume your actual procedure is valid and does what you want.

The problem is in your run-time variable declaration. You haven't specified a size for `x`, so it uses a default. On my DB, in SQL*Plus that seems to allow three characters but errors with four or more:

```
var x varchar2;

exec :x := 'a';
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
exec :x := 'ab';
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
exec :x := 'abc';
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
exec :x := 'abcd';
BEGIN :x := 'abcd'; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

The limit might be related to your character set, perhaps. SQL Developer allows more by default.

Anyway, specify the size for your variable:

```
var x varchar2(30);
exec CHK_LASTAPPTIME(:x);
```

You seem to be generating a number in your procedure, and then returning that as a string. Using the same data type would make this a bit simpler.

Comment: Cool! Yes I did shrink the code for posting purposes and the proc is valid. And specifying the size for X got rid of the error. Thanks.